# Fetching Data Anomalies in SQL (2 Columns)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with two columns and following data

```
ID NAME
1  ALPHA
1  ALPHA
2  BETA
1  BETA
```

First three rows are correct data, but in the last row someone accidentally entered ID 1 instead of ID 2, can anyone help me with a query to fetch multiple rows of ID for distinct names. I have tried the query below but its not yielding the correct result

SELECT F1.ID FROM myTable F1 WHERE F1.Name in
(SELECT DISTINCT F2.Name FROM myTable F2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you need *names* that have multiple IDs; right?

For sample data:

```
SQL> select * From test;

        ID NAME
---------- -----
         1 alpha
         1 alpha
         2 beta
         1 beta
```

Query, using `group by` and `having` clauses:

```
SQL> select name
  2  from test
  3  group by name
  4  having count(distinct id) > 1;

NAME
-----
beta

SQL>
```